# keyboard shortcut to send selection in RStudio to Terminal

Tags: r, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a keyboard shortcut to send to the *terminal* rather than the *console* (as labelled in RStudio).

For example, I want to run 
`$ Rscript hello_world.R`

`Ctrl+Enter` allows me to run `source("hello_world.R")` from the *console*, but I'm working with blocks of bash and python in an Rmd document, and I want to be able to run them without firing up a separate source code editor.

Comment: Can you use `system`?

Answer (score 3):

Try `ctrl+alt+enter`  I think it's what you are looking for.